# List is Null and adding Strings to that List does not work

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, adapter

I don't understand why it is always null at one place in the code.
Furthermore I don't have a solution for adding Strings from the Database to a List

```
public List<String> dbToString() {

// list where all Strings should be saved for an adapter
    List<String> allNamesTodos = null;

// getting List von database with all Items
    List<DB_Item> allItems = dbHelper.getAllItems();

    for (int j = 0; j < allItems.size(); j++) {

// here says the code, that allNamesTodos is null...
// Null pointer access: The variable allNamesTodos can only be null at this location

        allNamesTodos.add(allItems.get(j).getName());
    }

    return allNamesTodos;
```

and here is the one with the adapter:

```
SortItems sortTodos = new SortItems(this);
        List<String> todos = sortTodos.dbToString();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.items, R.id.label, todos);
```

hope, you can help me, thank you :)

Comment: List<String> allNamesTodos = null; say that it is null.

Comment: Are you trying to add something to a null list on purpose ?

Comment: lol `List<String> allNamesTodos = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: yes lol is the correct answer :D
I was soooo blind, sry... and thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `null` because you initialized it to null, and you can't add elements until you instantiate a `List` instance. You could change this,

```
List<String> allNamesTodos = null;
```

to

```
List<String> allNamesTodos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or, you could do it on the first add -

```
if (allNamesTodos == null) {
  allNamesTodos = new ArrayList<>();
}
// Then you can add elements.
allNamesTodos.add(allItems.get(j).getName());
```

Comment: OMG thank you, now I look very stupid I think...

Answer (score 0):

`variable = null` means the variable doesn't hold anything. *It doesn't hold an object*. So trying to access it, i.e. call any method on it, is like trying to call a method on *nothing*, and simply results in a `NullPointerException`.

You are confusing a `null` value, that means the variable doesn't hold an actual object, with an *empty list* - which is an actual object.

To construct an empty list, do the following:

```
List<Stuff> list = new ArrayList<Stuff>();
```

Than you can `add()` things to it.

Answer (score 0):

I (*) recommend to *always initialize variables*, so that you will never have to struggle with null values. Your problem will go away if you replace `= null`, which is useless anyway, with `= new ...`.

(*) I did not invent this principle, but read and learned about this while doing Pascal, Fortran, Basic long ago.